# Woo-commerce free shipping

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Not sure this question has been asked before.

My website has an option to offer free shipping when the order amount exceeds $150. In our online store some products have free shipping and some products have a flat rate of $45. So I made 2 shipping classes for them. If the order exceeds $150 customers will get free shipping despite of the purchased products.

In the shipping methods, I created 2 shipping methods. One is Flat rate and other one is Free shipping.

[image: Shipping methods]

[image: Flat Rate]
[image: Free Shipping]

The issue I am facing at the moment is even though the order amount exceeds $150 user has to select the free shipping option manually.

[image: Select free shipping]

This is annoying since some people forgot to select it manually and they are asking for refunds.

Could someone please tell how to activate free shipping automatically rather than selecting it manually? Where did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.